# How to casually inform the recruiter about my current job I have been only for 3 weeks

Tags: employer-relations, employees, employer

I have successfully passed 2 rounds of interview with the company I like to have my long term employment. However, I wasn't really vocal and honest about my current job which i am only working for 2-4 weeks.
How can i casually inform the recruiter about it if i am successful candidate for the position?

Comment: What, specifically, were you not honest and/or vocal about?  Did you indicate that you had been at your current job longer than 3 weeks?  Did you indicate that you didn't have a job currently?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actuallly mentioned I was still at my previous job and did not mention my current job which I am only at 3 weeks now. To make it clearer. I started work and already at my 3rd week at Company A (join in Feb this year). But in my resume and interview, I said that I was still in Company B. So in my resume, I did not indicate company A - instead put Company B March 2007 - Present, instead of March 2007 - Jan 2014.  Based on the flow of the interviews, I am pretty positive that I have a chance for the position and would like to correct that thing bothering me.

Answer (score 3):

At this point I would say nothing and hope the short stint does not show up on a background check (it might not given the short length).

You would have been better off being honest to begin with. There is no shame in admitting that the job was not a good fit or there were issues not obvious in an interview (e.g. hiring manager flat out lied about what you would be doing so you quit).

But lying to your next employer? That is likely to get your working relationship off to a really bad start: so bad you may not get hired. If you do get hired, management will likely view you as a risk for a long time until you prove yourself. What else did this person lie about?

Honesty is always the best course of action when it comes to employment, but in this case, *do not mention it, casually or not*.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are specifically asked about it, I wouldn't advise that you mention it as it will simply "muddy the waters". If the company recruiting you likes you and you pass a background check (if there's a need for one) the fact that you are currently working will not be that important as the company will be seeking to hire you. Also, unless you flat out lied and stated that you were still working at your former employer when you are not, then no one is likely to follow up on the matter if they want you as an employee.

In my opinion, if you are in a smaller industry, it may be of greater importance that you are changing jobs so quickly as it may cause rumors to spread. However, if you are in a large industry or you have a unique skill set, I would simply advise moving on to your new position and in the future being somewhat more forthright about your current employment situation when asked.